# Convert hyperlinks to HTML tags within string in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I need a formula that can take what is shown here in the left cell (a block of text with an unknown number of hyperlinks) and convert it to what is seen in the right cell (the same block of text but with the hyperlinks converted into html a tags). I'd like to do this programmatically as it's a huge spreadsheet and some of the cells will have a lot of hyperlinks. I'm happy to use a script for this but as non-coders may be doing some of the work, I would prefer to keep everything in Google Sheets (ie. I don't want to transfer the data anywhere in order to use Python, for example).

[image]

I'd be grateful for any suggestions as to how to go about this! I can extract a single url, but I'm unsure how to extract and unknown number, and then add the html tag back into the text.

Many thanks

PS. I've just been looking at some of the existing answers to similar questions, and I'm afraid I can't get them to work, hence posting this!

Comment: Maybe this could get you started [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76831290/how-can-i-convert-links-in-google-sheets-cell-data-to-html-anchor-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no function to get links you have to examine the RichText and build a new string using a custom function.  This function looks in the cell in the column before the custom function and returns the html tagged string.

[image]

```
function GetHyperlink() {
  let cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  cell = cell.offset(0,-1);
  let richText = cell.getRichTextValue();
  let runs = richText.getRuns();
  let text = "";
  runs.forEach( run => {
      let url = run.getLinkUrl();
      if( url ) {
        text = text.concat('<a href="'+url+'">'+run.getText()+'</a>');
      }
      else {
        text = text+run.getText();
      }
    }
  );
  return text;
}
```

Reference

- [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer))
- [Range.getRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRichTextValue())
- [RichTextValue.getRuns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getRuns())
- [RichTextValue.getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getText())